# Persist API data in AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to persist the fetched API data (Array) when reopening a React Native app without internet connection.

Fetching and storing the data in state and `AsyncStorage` works just fine using Axios.

When opening the app without internet connection, there is an endless load time, I cannot figure out how to trigger the catch promise and use my stored data as the new data for the state.

This is my code:

```
componentWillMount(){
        axios.get('http://example.com/api_get_request')
          .then((response) => {
              console.log('connection ok!');
              AsyncStorage.setItem('landen', JSON.stringify(response.data));
              this.setState({
                landen: response.data,
                loading: false,
              });
              //DATA SET TO STATE + ASYNCSTORAGE
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response);
            AsyncStorage.getItem('landen').then((value) => {
              this.setState({
                landen: JSON.parse(value),
                loading: false,
              });
              //NO CONNECTION -> ASYNC DATA
            });
          }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`NetInfo`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html) to check internet connection and as per connection execute your code like below.

```
componentWillMount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
    if (isConnected) {
      axios.get('http://example.com/api_get_request')
        .then((response) => {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('landen', JSON.stringify(response.data));
          this.setState({
            landen: response.data,
            loading: false,
          });
        })
    } else {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('landen').then((value) => {
        this.setState({
          landen: JSON.parse(value),
          loading: false,
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Please note, above code is not tested and you may have to fix few things here and there but you will get the concept. Also, you may have to add `catch` block to catch unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

For manage some little info is a good idea use `AsyncStorage`. But if you need manage all your app states, it's a good practice passing your code to Redux and use libraries like:

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist
https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline